# Why isn't my Android app recognizing the PNG in a sub-directory of the drawables directory?

Tags: android, kotlin

I thought I might sub-divide the drawables folder into folders for each of the screens, but now one of my XML files doesn't recognize the background image I want to use. What is the correct syntax to use a PNG from a specific folder?

[image]

[image]

Side question - is this not common practice? I sense that it's not since Android Studio didn't suggest this sub-directory for me in the intellisense.

Comment: you can create another resource folder under "main" and declare in app build.gradle
it works for me. I can subdirectory my resources for each screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdirectories for resources aren't supported at all. You can certainly split your app into many different modules (even to the level of one per screen) if you'd like as all modules will be merged together into your final apk